# Passing Request.QueryString integer value in a sql query from source code

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am trying to pass Request.QueryString integer value in a query from source code. How do i do it?

```
http://localhost:3738/WebSite3/UserDetails.aspx?Id=43
```

I want to pass id's value i.e 43 in query

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SLIITComDBConnectionString %>" 

    SelectCommand="SELECT Album.AlbumID, Album.DefaultPhotID, Album.AlbumName, PhotAlbum.Photo FROM Album INNER JOIN PhotAlbum ON Album.DefaultPhotID = PhotAlbum.PhotoID where album.userid= **Request.QueryString[id]** ">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [QueryStringParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.querystringparameter.querystringfield.aspx)

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SLIITComDBConnectionString %>" 

SelectCommand="SELECT Album.AlbumID, Album.DefaultPhotID, Album.AlbumName, PhotAlbum.Photo FROM Album INNER JOIN PhotAlbum ON Album.DefaultPhotID = PhotAlbum.PhotoID where album.userid= @userid ">
   <SelectParameters>
      <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="userid" Type="String"  QueryStringField="id" />
   </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
 <%=this.Request.QueryString["Id"]%>
```